# How to assing multiple values to multiple variables in one statement? c#

Tags: c#

I want to assign values to many variables at once. Something like this:

```
int a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

I know that won't work, but what I'm trying to do is assign the values like this:

```
int a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4 //... etc
```

In just one statement. 
I don't know if that is possible.

Comment: `int a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4, ... ;` doesn't work?

Comment: Very confusing what you are trying to achieve - as @lurker commented code in the post already "assigns multiple values to multiple variables"... Maybe you use "one statement" to mean something different than one statement?

Comment: @lurker [It sure does](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AcVSia).

Comment: @LewsTherin as I expected. :) OP said, *...but what I'm trying to do is assign the values like this:* which implied they hadn't tried it or thought it didn't work.

Comment: You just need a semi-colon at the end of your second code sample.

Comment: You can use Tuple deconstruction. I'm not sure if it is any better than manually assigning the variables though:   `var (a, b, c) = (1, 2, 3);`  and you can even mix types:  `var (a, b, c) = (1, "Hello", 3);`

Comment: @ChrisDunaway That's kind of what I wanted to do, but as _Display Name_ said in their answer, the close I'm going to get to what I was trying to do is assigning the values one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is about as close as you're going to get. C# doesn't allow what you want. But if you want an easy way to paste an array of variable values, this is the best one can do in C#.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] values = { 1, 2, 7, 8, 42 };

            int a = values[0];
            int b = values[1];
            int c = values[2];
            int d = values[3];
            int e = values[4];

            Console.WriteLine($"a={a}, b={b}, c={c}, d={d}, e={e}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are assigning values each on a separate line (and not sure why you're allocating the array for this). Didn't the OP already have a single line solution in the original question (`int a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4;`)? How is this better?

Comment: @RufusL the question asked seemed to be how to assign an array to individual named variables. C# doesn't actually support that.  This is a close as one can get with C# syntax.

Comment: Oh, i didn't see anything about an array, but maybe that is what he meant.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to assign the values of an array to the variables, but I guess there is no simpler way to do it than the one I used as an example in my question.

Answer (score 2):

The C# allow that, a single statement can assign multiple local variables

```
int i = 5, y = 10, x = 100;
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", i, y, x);

const string s = "dot", a = "net", m = "perls";
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", s, a, m);

int j = 1, k, z;
Console.WriteLine(j);
k = z = 0; // Initialize the others
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", k, z);
```